# Java: How To Execute External Command As User?

Tags: java, processbuilder, runtime.exec

***I would like to know how I could execute the following command as a specified user (hduser) in Java:***
I must first execute: ***"sudo su hduser"***
And then aim to execute the following command:***"hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar /Primes/numbers-small.txt /Primes/"***

I have tried using ProcessBuilder with a number of different arguments, however have been unsuccessful thus far. If someone could please advise me as to where exactly I'm going wrong, it would honestly mean a lot :)

My code, for reference can be seen below.

```
            ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(); 
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            if(dataset.getSelectedItem().equals("Small Dataset: 750,000 Numbers")){
                p = new ProcessBuilder("sudo su hduser", "hadoop", "jar", "/executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar", "/Primes/numbers-small.txt", "/Primes/");
            }
            else if (dataset.getSelectedItem().equals("Medium Dataset: 1,500,000 Numbers")){
                p = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "su", "hduser", "hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar /Primes/numbers-medium.txt /Primes/");
            }
            else if (dataset.getSelectedItem().equals("Large Dataset: 10,000,000 Numbers")){
                p = new ProcessBuilder("sudo su", "hduser", "hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar", "/Primes/numbers-large.txt", "/Primes/");
            }

            try {
                p.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage()); 
            }
```

Please note that I did try a multitude of arguments (hence, you can see my previous failed attempts in the code above). Please forgive me if I'm making some blatant mistake (still a relatively young coder) - I've done a fair bit of reading around these methods, however I am unable to figure out the issue and cause behind this failure.

PS: I feel as though its important to note that as the 'default user', should something along the likes of 'sudo su hduser -c hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar /Primes/numbers-small.txt /Primes/' be run, I am receiving a 'hadoop: command not found' error (despite the command running fine after executing the two portions of the command separately - switching the user first - and then executing the command).

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Why `sudo su` and not just `sudo -u`?

Comment: @shmosel the problem is that the command shown above is unable to execute as desired, perhaps because of a tokenisation issue that I am unaware of. The above commands fail to execute within the correct procedure as mentioned within the question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, unfortunately sudo -u produces the same result, and for this reason is different from the 'duplicated question' shown above.

Comment: *unable to execute as desired* is a pretty vague problem description.

Comment: My bad @shmosel, what I meant to say was that: the command above does not allow my program to (firstly) the user of the new sub-shell process that is created, and then (secondly) execute the command "hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar /Primes/numbers-small.txt /Primes/ " (which I am able to do directly from the Terminal / Console window). 

Should I try to run "sudo -u hduser -c hadoop jar /executables/Primes/jar/execute.jar /Primes/numbers-small.txt /Primes/" (in Terminal) I am presented with 'hadoop: command not found' error.

Comment: @Vilitaria: If you pass the full path to the `hadoop` executable, does that work? When logged in with a shell where you *can* run `hadoop`, what does `type hadoop` tell you?